# how to access path/file of a Remote Desktop using c#.I am able to connect with remote desktop but not able to access the file/path

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop

```
        var rdp = new MsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting();
        rdp.Server = "";`//server`
        rdp.UserName = "";`//username`
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.ClearTextPassword = "";`//password`
        rdp.Connect();
        if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\abc.text"))
        {
                //Getting error in directory exist.
        }
```

I am able to connect with remote desktop but not able to access the file/path.Getting error in directory exist.